# ng-options filter by value in another dropdown one data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have read some example in [ng-options filter by value in another dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357097/ng-options-filter-by-value-in-another-dropdown).

But in my case the data is in one scope.

I have try

```
Make:
<select ng-model="makeng" ng-options="option.id as option.display for option in makes">
    <option ng-disabled="true"  ng-selected="true" value="">Select a make</option>
</select>


Model:
<select ng-model="modelng" ng-options="option.data.name for option in makes | filter:{id:makeng}">
    <option ng-disabled="true"  ng-selected="true" value="">Select a model</option>
</select>
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/MlbBcVso57H3tyVEJa8o?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the filter at all:

http://plnkr.co/edit/OjM1yJPYV1vQh5HRDNQ1?p=preview

Make:

```
<select ng-model="makeng" ng-options="option as option.display for option in makes">
    <option ng-disabled="true"  ng-selected="true" value="">Select a make</option>
</select>
```

Model:

```
<select ng-model="modelng" ng-options="option.name for option in makes[makes.indexOf(makeng)].data">
    <option ng-disabled="true"  ng-selected="true" value="">Select a model</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, @HankScorpio. But when I select `TOYOTA` the new options is not correct it should be `DATA1 DATA2`

Comment: Ah right, I updated the answer. This version changes with value of makeng to be the full object (rather than just the id). I'd recommend that as the simplest option.